# use of "of tomorrow" in sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

can i use "**between 3:00 PM to 4:00 PM of tomorrow**" in any sentence instead of "between 3:00 PM to 4:00 PM by tomorrow".

Comment: Change ***to*** to ***and*** (or change ***between*** to ***from***), and lose the ***of***. This is either "too basic" or it's proofreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*By tomorrow* is it will happen between the present and the time stated, so if *by* is used, then it should say *4:00 PM by tomorrow.* A time frame restricts the event to the time frame listed as in your example, which means *by* is incorrect, according to your example. *Between 3:00 PM to 4:00 PM of tomorrow* is saying that the event will happen between the time frame of 3:00 PM to 4:00 PM of the following day. I hope this helps you out because it really depends on what you want to say, and saying it correctly.